# Increasing E(Y|X) implies increasing E(X|Y)

Tags: conditional-expectation

I guessed the following statement about Conditional Expectations and tried to prove it unsuccessfully:

if $E(Y|X=x)$ is strictly increasing in $x$, then $E(X|Y=y)$ is strictly increasing in $y$.

Any hint? I also tried to find a counter-example.

I thought that this statement must be true since it seemed to me as the stochastic counterpart of the following statement: the inverse of an increasing function is also increasing. Also, it is closely related to the following: the regression coefficient of $Y$ on $X$ has the same sign that the regression coefficient of $X$ on $Y$. But I was not able to prove it yet. I also checked some parametric cases, like the joint normal distribution, where the statement is true. I also consulted some main textbooks, and google scholar but no success.

Appreciate any insight.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thanks for help. My question is an abstract question. Now I tried to explain how I got to this ''conjecture''. The statement can be wrong but I was not able to find a counterexample either.

Comment: The additions are what we are looking for. hopefully someone in that field will see it.

Comment: If I understand correctly your example, in that case both conditional expectations are decreasing.

Comment: You are right, but another answer is given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is a counterexample:

|  | Y = 0 | Y = 1 | Y = 100 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X = 0 | 0% | 50% | 0% |
| X = 1 | 25% | 0% | 25% |

since $E(Y|X=0) =  1$ and $E(Y|X=1) = 50$, the first condition is satisfied, but since $E(X|Y=0) = 1$ and $E(X|Y=1) = 0$, the second condition is not satisfied.

Comment: apologies for awkwad formatting, it seems table support is rather limited.

Comment: Beautiful and simple! Thanks a lot. I am thinking what is the condition on the shape of the joint distribution that makes the statement correct. Looking at your example, the joint cdf is concave.

Comment: yeah, that sounds right - I suspect if you added the condition that each P(Y|X=x) and each P(X|Y=y) were functions with a single hump, then the theorem would hold.  Of course, that limits you to talking about continuous random variables, for the most part.

Comment: Super Interesting. Any idea of the proof? Sounds to me that given single-hump means concavity or convexity, Jensen inequality might not be useful.

Comment: actually, upon further thought that's probably not correct either - I don't have a counterexample I can write down since it's basically just a 3d surface that I'm visualizing, but I think that you could come up with a counterexample that's all single-hump funtions.